# UICollectionViewController cells disappear on tap or scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add CollectionView on tabBarController

for grid collectionView

So I made a UICollectionViewController as another swift file

I added to ViewController(Navigation Controller) as `UICollectionViewController.view`

But cells disappear immediately when I tap the collectionView.
[image: before-tap]
[image: after-tap]

I think I did follow the guide and search for two days.. but I can't fix it...

some people are saying it is the problem of add a collectionView as a subview, but I don't get it

This is custom UICollectionView, MyFeedController.swift

```swift
import UIKit

class MyFeedController: BaseListController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .purple

        collectionView.register(MyFeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.delegate = self


        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyFeedCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        return .init(width: (screenWidth - 4 - 4) / 3, height: (screenWidth - 4 - 4) / 3)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .init(top: 2, left: 0, bottom: 2, right: 0)
    }
}
```

And It's my custom Cell, MyFeedCell.swift It's simple

```swift
//
//  MyFeedCollectionController.swift
//  My-Lord-Cat
//
//  Created by Cory Kim on 17/07/2019.
//  Copyright © 2019 Cory Kim. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class MyFeedController: BaseListController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let cellId = "cellId"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.backgroundColor = .purple

        collectionView.register(MyFeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView.delegate = self


        if let layout = collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        }
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyFeedCell
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        return .init(width: (screenWidth - 4 - 4) / 3, height: (screenWidth - 4 - 4) / 3)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return .init(top: 2, left: 0, bottom: 2, right: 0)
    }
}
```

So I added MyFeedController to MyPageController(which is a UIViewController)

```swift
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true

        setupLayout()
        setupMyFeedGridCollectionView()
    }

    // other views are set on setupLayout()

    fileprivate func setupMyFeedGridCollectionView() {

        let myFeedController = MyFeedController()

        view.addSubview(myFeedController.view)
        myFeedController.view.anchor(top: infoStackView.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    // anchor method is extension for autolayout
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you're setting the collectionView's dataSource.  Set a breakpoint at this line to make sure it's getting called:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyFeedCell
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I set a breakpoint as you said and it's called well. Also I specified `collectionView.dataSource = self` but it's same :(

Comment: Your view hierarchy looks like it could be leading to the problem.  You're currently adding the view of another view controller to 'MyPageController'?

Comment: yes! adding MyFeedController(UicollectionView) to MyPageController(UIViewController)